# onchange() not firing in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Here's the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xpkFf/330/
If you open the dialog, enter a username and password, press the button and get prompted with Firefox's "remember my password", the onchange will not work the first time you choose an option from the dropdown if the click on the dropdown causes the prompt to dismiss. Anyone knows a way around it?

Edit : Jsfiddle seems down, here's a jsbin if anyone can reproduce my problem http://jsbin.com/wecasehanu/1/

HTML

```
 <div id="dialog">
        <form autocomplete="off">
            <input id="username" type="text"/>
            <input id="password" type="password"/>
            <button type="submit" style="height:30px;width:30px;"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="open">Open dialog</a>
    <select id="ih8ff">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
```

Javascript

```
$('#open').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');

});

$('#ih8ff').change(function(){
alert("changed");
});

$('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: false
});
```

Comment: It work for me. In Firefox or Chrome. But you need to actually change the select not selecing the same value.

Comment: The behavior only happens in firefox. You have to let the "remember my password" prompt opened, then try selecting the second value from the dropdown

Comment: There is no remember my password in your code.

Comment: It's fired from firefox when you enter a username and password and press a button, try the jsfiddle in firefox

Comment: I'm still unable to reproduce. I got alert after I click on select when there is a remember password prompt.

Comment: That's odd, I tried from 3 different computers from 3 different locations and always got the same result.

Comment: Did you try it in firefox? If so, mind telling me which version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a hack around it. Here's a jsfiddle showing it : http://jsfiddle.net/xpkFf/332/
After testing, all events were cancelled after clicking the dropdown except the mouseup, so I just captured the coordinates of the mouse and made sure I was in a select box. I submitted the bug to mozilla hopefully they will fix it.

Code

```
$('#open').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');

});
var ddstate;
$('#ih8ff').change(function(){
    alert("changed");
});
$('#ih8ff').click(function(){
if(ddstate==undefined)
    ddstate=true;
});
$('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: false
});
$(window).mouseup(function(e) {
    if(ddstate){
        var x= e.clientX;
        var y= e.clientY;
        if(x > 85 && x < 119 && y > 42 && y < 62)
        {
            $("#ih8ff").val("2");
            $('#ih8ff').change();
            ddstate=false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `on input` instead. Chrome and Safari have a different way of handling  `change` than Firefox. However, `input` events are handled in the same way.

```js
$('#open').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');

});

$('#ih8ff').on("input change",function(){
alert("changed");
});

$('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog">
        <form autocomplete="off">
            <input id="username" type="text"/>
            <input id="password" type="password"/>
            <button type="submit" style="height:30px;width:30px;"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="open">Open dialog</a>
    <select id="ih8ff">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: oninput is not valid for select. In your example the dialog does not work so the "remember my password" prompt can't fire.

Comment: And your code seems to only run in Chrome, not IE and FF

Comment: That is strange. I added `input change` now on the events but it fires twice.  However, your own fiddle works right away on Firefox for me.. Hm, strange..

Comment: With my fiddle in firefox, did you 1)open dialog 2)enter user pass 3) press button 4)dont touch the firefox remember password prompt 5)select option 2 ? What OS do you use?

Comment: Yes, yes, yes and yes. Windows 7 x64.